# Does Eigen Library in C++ have a dynamic vector or matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a way to set a dynamic vector or matrix in Eigen library? If not, is there a way to still use the Eigen library in conjunction with another class like `vector`?

For example let's say I have `n*1` matrix called `MatrixXd S(n,1);` Now for simplicity let `n=3` and `S = 4 2 6`. Pretend that the elements in `S` are future stock prices and let `K = 2` which will be the strike price. Don't worry you won't need to understand the terminology of an option. Now say I want to know at what positions of `S` will we have `S - K > 0` and say I want to store these positions in a vector call `b`.

Clearly, depending on the elements of `S` the vector `b` will be of a different size. Thus, I need to have `b` being of a **dynamic** variable. The only class I am familiar with that allows this is the vector class i.e., `#include <vector>`.

My question is as follows: Is it okay to use the Eigen library and the `#include <vector>` class together? Note that I will be performing operations of `b` with the Eigen library vectors and matrices I have created.

If I am not making sense, or if my question is unclear please let me know and I will clarify as much as possible.

Comment: Why not use `Eigen::VectorXd` or some other form of the vector template? Yes, Eigen does support dynamically sized matrices and vectors; you're already using `Eigen::MatrixXd`, which is a dynamically-sized matrix of `double`s.

Comment: @JasonR Oh, I did not know that I thought we need to specify the size of the vector or matrix in Eigen?

Comment: You should start by reading [Eigen's introductory documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html).

Comment: @JasonR I have but I guess I did not really understand it, I will give it another read

Comment: @JasonR should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. It's presented in the "*A simple first program*" of [Getting started](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
int main()
{
  MatrixXd m(2,2);
  m(0,0) = 3;
  m(1,0) = 2.5;
  m(0,1) = -1;
  m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

You do need to pass the size to the constructor, but it's works like a `vector`. You can [`resize`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a9fd0703bd7bfe89d6dc80e2ce87c312a) it later on too.

`MatrixXd` is a convenient typedef  to a [`Matrix`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) template which uses `Dynamic` as a template value for `Rows`, and `Cols`. It's basically `Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic>`.

So you can have not only dynamic sized vectors and matrices, but also arbitrarily large fixed-size ones. Eigen does pretty nifty optimizations for small matrices, so using a fixed size there might be beneficial.

Comment: Okay so lets say I have VectorXd itmP(4,1) then as it is passed through a for loop the size should be cut down to two. That shouldn't be a problem then right?

Comment: Yup, you gotta start reading the docs: [`resize`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1PlainObjectBase.html#a9fd0703bd7bfe89d6dc80e2ce87c312a). Eigen's are pretty friendly.